# Stop animation from playing more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS code. Whenever I scroll across the skills div, the animation repeats. I want it to only load once when the user reaches the div and then never repeat unless the page is loaded again.

```
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('#skills').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    var x = true;

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop ); 
        if(pTop > oTop){
              start_doughnut_animation();

        }
    });
});
```

It repeats even if I scroll in the middle of the animation being executed.I tried using a boolean but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flag variable, something like:

```
$(function() {
    var oTop = $('#skills').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    var x = true,
        oneTime = false;

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var pTop = $('body').scrollTop();
        console.log( pTop + ' - ' + oTop ); 
        if(pTop > oTop && !oneTime){  // check if oneTimeis also false
              start_doughnut_animation();
              oneTime = true; // set oneTime so this can't happen again
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give yourself an escape from the loop.

Check first if the function has been run. For example "if var executed is false", then run your animation function. And at the end of the animation, set your escape variable executed to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery api one() this set the element to run only once for example use

```
 $(window).one( "scroll", function() {
```

You can find more documentation here http://api.jquery.com/one/